# I am calculating total amount spent per customer in mysql, using join with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables:

customer (customer_id, last_name, first_name)

products (isbn, book title, ListPrice)

order_has_products (customer_id, order_id, isbn)

orders (order_id, customer_id)

I want to calculate the total amount spent on books per customer.It seems to me I will be joining 3 tables.Do i need a "quantity" column to be able to do this?

Comment: do you have some data and DDL to be shared on http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected output to your question.

Comment: Why is the `customer_id` in the `order_has_products` relation?  Shouldn't the `orders` relation have the `customer_id`?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(products.ListPrice) FROM order_has_products
INNER JOIN products on order_has_products.isbn = products.isbn
GROUP BY order_has_products.customer_id
```

Comment: Actually didn't read the question correctly. Updated. Thanks :)

Comment: I think there is a shorter version: joining `order_has_products` and `products` is sufficient already, because you don't take any attributes from `customer` except for `customer_id` (which is already in `order_has_products`.

Comment: Yaah if you don't need any data from users table then its TRUE. :)

Comment: You're not querying for any data from `customers` - so you don't need to include it in the join.  Of course this is only true because, weirdly enough, the `customer_id` is in the `order_has_products` relation, which makes no sense and is not necessary.